# Remove duplicate elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to remove duplicate elements that exist within the same tuple in a list as shown

```
list_1= [('nissan', 'nissan'), ('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
```

the output I'd like to make is :

```
list_1= [('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
```

I tried using "set" but it only removes duplicate tuples!

Comment: `list2 = [tup for tup in list1 if tup[0] != tup[1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, which means to generate a new list by iterating on existing list (possibly filtering by condition):

```py
list_1 = [i for i in list_1 if i[0] != i[1]]
```

Comment: You can expand this with `[i for i in list_1 if len(set(i)) == len(i)]` for tuples with more than 2 elements

Comment: super helpful since I was thinking the same if tuples expanded to more than 2 elements, thanks

Answer (score 0):

see

```
lst = [('nissan', 'nissan'), ('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
no_dups = [x for x in lst if x[0] != x[1]]
print(no_dups)
```

output

```
[('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be easily solved using `set`

```
list_1= [('nissan', 'nissan'), ('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
res=[]
for i in list_1:
    if len(set(i)) == 2:
        res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `filter`:

```
list_1= [('nissan', 'nissan'), ('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]

list_no_duplicates = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], list_1))

print(list_no_duplicates)
# [('buy', 'toyota'), ('sale', 'toyota'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output that you have mentioned is different then what you asked in the question

but if You want to remove duplicate elements that exist within the same tuple in a list you can do it by
`list_1 = [x for x in [tuple(set(item)) for item in list_1]]`

which gives output
`[('nissan',), ('buy', 'toyota'), ('toyota', 'sale'), ('cheap', 'toyota')]`